# What's the difference between Minecraft 1.8 pre-release and actual release?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What has changed between the 1.8 prereleases, and the new, actual release?

Comment: probably the actual release is just to make it official

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jens and Notch fixed a ton of bugs between the pre-release and the release, [including](https://twitter.com/#!/jeb_/status/113289341761093632):

> - SSP chunk memory leak
> - Mineshaft density (half now)
> - Increased stronghold count to 3 per map instead of one
> - Furnace tile entity crash
> - Crafting bench ghost items
> - Vines (and leaves) crash in nether
> - Use item animation in SMP (blocking and eating)
> - Blocking in SMP
> - Sprinting with right-click or sneaking
> - Added some blocks to creative mode
> - Fixed dropping items
> - Nothing can be eaten in creative mode
> - Enderman client-side problems
> - Chicken and cow drop burned food
> - Squids drop exp
> - 1.7 worlds should get structures
> - Farmlands rejecting melon and pumpkin seeds
> - Bonemeal on melons and pumpkins
> - Bonemeal on mushroom only works on dirt or grass
> - Added item drops for cracked and mossy smooth stone brick
> - Adjusted fog strength at low positions

Changes reported by Jens on Twitter:

- [Fixed experience orb excessive spawning bug in SMP](https://twitter.com/#!/jeb_/status/113343037215752192)
- [Made cave spider poison scale with difficulty](https://twitter.com/#!/jeb_/status/113670924443729920)
- [Nerfed sprinting speed](https://twitter.com/#!/jeb_/status/113729246588964864)
- [Fog toggle key 'F' re-added, then removed, then re-added again as 'F3' + 'F'](https://twitter.com/#!/jeb_/status/113879474193432576)
- [Fixed crash when adding too many items to a double-chest in SMP](https://twitter.com/#!/jeb_/status/113890800957530113)

Changes reported by Notch on Twitter:

- ["Tweaked" Endermen](https://twitter.com/#!/notch/status/113639625364480001) (this potentially refers to [the change in eye color and particle effect](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/30383/3389) for Endermen in the final release)
- [Fixed issue with holding down right-click to place multiple blocks](https://twitter.com/#!/notch/status/113657465438089216)
- [Nerfed vine growth](https://twitter.com/#!/notch/status/113547746585214976)
- [Two unnamed fixes and two unnamed tweaks](https://twitter.com/#!/notch/status/113534302238687232)

Comment: Nerfed sprint speed?  :(