# What is the difference between green and purple Endermen?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've already seen the green-eyed endermen:
[image]

and I know the basic story behind them. But what about these purple guys:
[image]

with bright purple eyes and sparkly nether-portal-like particles around them? What's the difference between the two?

Comment: An `XOR` operation on the colour value?

Comment: The difference is one of them looked nice and original and the other is purple and shiny which only enhances how horrible the Endermen really are, and by horrible I mean there the worst mob, or character ever seen in a video game...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a quote from the Minecraft wiki:

> In the final release of 1.8, the Enderman's eyes are now purple, and instead of emitting smoke they emit nether portal particles.

So there's no difference between them, they have only changed up the skin a bit from the pre-release to the actual release.

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enderman#Trivia)

Comment: Also my guess is that Notch wanted it to seem that they came from the Nether instead of the far lands, like they were supposed to be orginally.

Comment: I still insist that "Farlanders" would have been a better name...

Comment: @RCIX: I presumed it was a play on 'Ander' (Other) in German with reference to 'Slender Man'. The combination of which sounds suitably spooky to me.